# I want to create an angular app to show live code preview like Jsbin

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm creating the Angular app which lets user save his html code (maybe it has style and script tag to control the view) and there is a live preview next to it. User can save the code and other users can come to see the code and the preview. I also worry about the security because of script tag and I want the script to work only with the code that user provides (Not allow to control or get the data in the parent frame). So I need some suggesting of how to do it.

I have tried the preview with iFrame by giving the value through the 'srcdoc' property, but it looks like the security is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You would not need to use an iframe in that situation, you can just render an HTML string inside of a div element using the innerHtml input like so:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Where htmlString is a string containing the HTML code. You will have to sanitize the content of that variable with the DomSanitizer.

```
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.htmlString = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(yourHTMLString);
}
```

Comment: If user adds some script like for hacking, will this method safe?

Comment: Technically that is what the DomSanitizer is there for, to remove any unsafe scripting, so it should be safe in theory. You know how these things are though, so I would not solely rely on that if you are going to store HTML in your database, I would also add some security checking in your back-end as well.